# Equivalent expression in Python

Tags: python, c, numpy

I am a Python n00b and at the risk of asking an elementary question, here I go.

I am porting some code from C to Python for various reasons that I don't want to go into.

In the C code, I have some code that I reproduce below.

```
float table[3][101][4];
int kx[6] = {0,1,0,2,1,0};
int kz[6] = {0,0,1,0,1,2};
```

I want an equivalent Python expression for the C code below:

```
float *px, *pz;
int lx = LX; /* constant defined somewhere else */
int lz = LZ; /* constant defined somewhere else */
px = &(table[kx[i]][0][0])+lx;
pz = &(table[kz[i]][0][0])+lz;
```

Can someone please help me by giving me the equivalent expression in Python?

Comment: If you wrap whatever you need in structs you can just use them from python directly instead of trying to implement low level functionality in a high level language which is a recipe for tears

Comment: This first code block is easy to convert but the second is looks scary - what do you do with px and pz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the thing... you can't do pointers in python, so what you're showing here is not "portable" in the sense that:

```
float *px, *pz;    <-- this doesn't exist
int lx = LX; /* constant defined somewhere else */
int lz = LZ; /* constant defined somewhere else */
px = &(table[kx[i]][0][0])+lx;
pz = &(table[kz[i]][0][0])+lz;
^    ^                      ^
|    |                      |
+----+----------------------+---- Therefore none of this makes any sense...
```

What you're trying to do is have a pointer to some offset in your multidimensional array `table`, because you can't do that in python, you don't want to "port" this code verbatim.

Follow the logic beyond this, what are you *doing* with `px` and `pz`? That is the code you need to understand to try and port.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent for your C code, since Python has no pointers or pointer arithmetic. Instead, refactor your code to index into the table with bracket notation.

```
table[kx[i]][0][lx] = 3
```

would be a rough equivalent of the C

```
px = &(table[kx[i]][0][0])+lx;
*px = 3;
```

Note that in Python, your table would not be contiguous. In particular, while this might work in C:

```
px[10] = 3; // Bounds violation!
```

This will IndexError in Python:

```
table[kx[i]][0][lx + 10] = 3
```

Comment: `"in Python, your table would not be contiguous"` - are you sure about that? I had [read](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) `"The actual representation of values is determined by the machine architecture (strictly speaking, by the C implementation)."` which sure sounds like the arrays would be contiguous in python.

Comment: An array would be contiguous, but the table wouldn't be an array. Python doesn't support multidimensional arrays; most code that needs a multidimensional grid of values either uses a list of lists (of lists... for as many levels as needed) or a NumPy ndarray. Some ndarrays are contiguous, but a list of lists definitely isn't. (Also, don't use Python arrays unless you have a very good, specific reason to do so. For most use cases, you want a list.)